# syntax error in CROSS APPLY

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, dmv

I'm trying to run a simple query to find the queries with the highest average CPU time.  The code is literally copy-pasted from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181929%28v=sql.105%29):

```
SELECT TOP 5 total_worker_time/execution_count AS [Avg CPU Time],
    SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1, 
        ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
          WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
         ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
         END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
ORDER BY total_worker_time/execution_count DESC;
```

Problem is, SQL Server is complaining about a syntax error in line 8 at the parameter to `sys.dm_exec_sql_text`: `qs.sql_handle` which unhelpfully reads

```
Incorrect syntax near '.'.
```

I cannot, for the life of me, figure out what's wrong with the query. Any ideas?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

It means that you are either

1. not running SQL Server 2005; or more likely
2. not running in Compatibility mode 90 or above

You can change it to 90 or above using, but it ***could very well*** break a lot of applications.

```
alter database MyDataBaseName set compatibility_level = 90
```

The easiest solution on SQL Server 2005 and above is simply to run it from "master" or "tempdb", e.g.

```
USE tempdb;
SELECT TOP 5 total_worker_time/execution_count AS [Avg CPU Time],
    SUBSTRING(st.text, (qs.statement_start_offset/2)+1, 
        ((CASE qs.statement_end_offset
          WHEN -1 THEN DATALENGTH(st.text)
         ELSE qs.statement_end_offset
         END - qs.statement_start_offset)/2) + 1) AS statement_text
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats AS qs
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(qs.sql_handle) AS st
ORDER BY total_worker_time/execution_count DESC;
```

Comment: I completely forgot about compatibility levels! I'm working with SQL Server 2008 R2, but compatibility level is set to 80 on this particular db (for no good reason).

Comment: this answer works, but is it possible to execute a query like this in a stored procedure?  Because you can't use `USE master;` in a stored procedure.